# Postgresql server using too much CPU

Tags: postgresql

I got a rails api server along with a PostgreSQL server on a Digital Ocean machine. On Digital Ocean's dashboard, I see that the CPU has it's average on 50%, although this machine has really low usage. Using top, I found out that the cause was Postgres server:

[image: top]

Using `top -c -b -n 1 -u postgres`:

[image: postgresql top]

This is basically the default installation of pgsql 9.6 on an Ubuntu 16.04 box. What might be happening? What the heck is ./x4226170084 process using all my CPU?

Comment: That's a process being run by the `postgres` user, but it is not a normal postgres process. The name of the executable makes me concerned that your system has been compromised and somebody is running an executable in a privileged account.

Comment: check if queryes are running https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685530/postgresql-check-if-query-is-still-running

Comment: You could check which query that is. The `pid` from the unix process is the one also shown in `pg_stat_activity`

Comment: Yeah, I'm another vote for "you've been rooted". I'm concerned that it seems to be running under the postgres user.

Comment: Craig, I wonder if someone found a vector into pgsql via something like sql injection here. Yeah another vote for "you've been rooted"

Comment: How can I find out if I been rooted? 
How can I fix this?

Comment: @Rafanelson, that's a whole separate, non-postgres-related question. I recommend talking to any security or systems people in your organization. You can also ask at https://serverfault.com/ or https://security.stackexchange.com/